# Can I run mixed models in SPSS applying bootstrap (using "cluster bootsrap")?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, spss, bootstrap

I have utilized the ClusterBootstrap package in R to run bootstrap analysis for mixed models. Is this possible in SPSS? Using the BOOTSTRAP-command in SPSS combined with

> /RANDOM=INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(id) COVTYPE(VC)

does not work for repeated measures data unless there is a way to identify the clusters to be sampled. As such the bootstrap is just sampling rows of the data and I want it to sample all measurements of the selected subjects (often called "cluster bootstrap").

Comment: Before someone votes to close this as "software-related" - in my opinion, it should stay open, because it does require statistical understanding to answer. See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352.

Comment: I'm surprised this is not available directly from the MIXED command frankly, but I guess it isn't: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/29.0.0?topic=reference-mixed

Comment: Have you looked over the documentation for the BOOTSTRAP command? Specifically, you might be interested in the STRATIFIED option of the SAMPLING subcommand: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/29.0.0?topic=bootstrap-sampling-subcommand-command It says "Specify one or more variables that define strata within the dataset. This performs case resampling with replacement from the original dataset, *within* the strata defined by the cross-classification of strata variables, preserving the size of each stratum."

Comment: @patrickcoulombe :    I checked the options of the BOOTSTRAP command, and none of them correspond to cluster bootstrap. In particular, stratified bootstrap is not what I want. Stratified bootstrap is for forcing the bootstrap samples to preserve the same numbers of, say, men and women,  as the original sample, i.e. bootstrapping separately within each stratum.